# Kivy: How Can I Pass Arguments to a Callback, then Determine Those Arguments Via Introspection?

Tags: python, callback, kivy, event-handling, bind

On page 247 of [the 2.2.0 version of the Kivy Documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/kivy/latest/kivy.pdf)there is an app demonstrating various ways to bind a callback to a button. The one I'm having trouble with is btn4. The comments for this button state:

> 

```
# You can also declare a function that accepts a variable number of
# positional and keyword arguments and use introspection to determine
# what is being passed in. This is very handy for debugging as well
# as function re-use. Here, we use standard event binding to a function
# that accepts optional positional and keyword arguments.
```

However, when this code is run and btn4 is pressed, the argument list is empty, so this isn't really a complete example.

I've been banging on this for two days without any luck. Perhaps I just don't understand Python well enough... or maybe it's Kivy I don't understand well enough...

Anyway, I've pared down the code to include just btn4. If someone could show me how arguments are passed into the on_anything() method so that the print() statement has something to print, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks. Here's the code:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class DemoBox(BoxLayout):
    """
    This class demonstrates various techniques that can be used
    for binding to events. Although parts could be made more optimal,
    advanced Python concepts are avoided for the sake of readability
    and clarity.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DemoBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        # You can also declare a function that accepts a variable number of
        # positional and keyword arguments and use introspection to determine
        # what is being passed in. This is very handy for debugging as well
        # as function re-use. Here, we use standard event binding to a function
        # that accepts optional positional and keyword arguments.
        btn4 = Button(text = "Use a flexible function")
        btn4.bind(on_press = self.on_anything)

        self.add_widget(btn4)
            
    def on_anything(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('The flexible function has *args of', str(args), "and **kwargs of", str(kwargs))
    
class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DemoBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoApp().run()
```

I've tried adding arguments to bind(), but I get an error. I really don't know what else to try.

Comment: What's the output you are getting when you press the button?

Comment: This part of the documentation is rather confusing. `btn4.bind(on_press = self.on_anything)` works exactly in the same way as `btn.bind(on_press=self.on_event)`, and the callback will be passed the same arguments. What this was meant to demonstrate is that you can pass an overloaded function, which can be bound to multiple different events where it is called with different signatures, e.g. also `btn2.bind(state=self.on_anything)` would work. This is just Python, not specific to Kivy.

Comment: You have to pass some optional args or kwargs (using `lambda` or `partial`) in order to use those. And the next example (`btn5`) demonstrates exactly that.

Comment: [Bergi] The output is a pointer to the button object. It takes the form: (<__main__.MyButton object at 0x00000246E74A3C30>,)

Comment: [ApuCoder] So... Then my understanding is that if it uses an anonymous function, it's the same as btn3 from the same demo.

Comment: [Bergi] "This part of the documentation is confusing." LOL Yes. Yes, it is. :)

Comment: One final question... If the btn4 example is just an incomplete version of the btn3 example (which uses a lambda) can anyone tell me why the demo includes both? It just seems misleading to me.